# getting force close click onlistview item on device but working well in emulator

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview, android-custom-view

**homeactivity.class**

```
lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {                      if(image_details.get(position).getQueryType().equals("service_appointment")){       
     Intent intent1=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SingleClick.class);
     Bundle b = new Bundle(); 
     b.putString("UserName", username);
     b.putString("Password",password);
     b.putString("id", image_details.get(position).getServiceRequestnum());
     b.putString("id3", image_details.get(position).getId());
     intent1.putExtras(b);
     startActivity(intent1); 

    }
    else  { 
     Intent intent2=new Intent(HomeActivity.this,SingleClickComment.class);
     Bundle b = new Bundle();
     b.putString("UserName", username);                     
     b.putString("Password",password);
     b.putString("id", image_details.get(position).getId());
     intent2.putExtras(b);
     startActivity(intent2);
     }
    });
```

**SingleClickComment.class**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.singleclick);   
enquiry=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.serviceEnduiry_Id);  
servicestatus=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.serviceappointmentstatus); 
count1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Count1);
time1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Time1);  
comment1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Comment1);  
description1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.DEscription1); 
count3=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Count2);     
singleClickComment=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.singleclickcommententry);             
singleClick=(Button) findViewById(R.id.singleclickcommentbutton);                 
ArrayList<Comment> image_details = new ArrayList<Comment>();
image_details = GetSearchResults();
System.out.println("imagedetails:"+image_details);
final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list10);
lv1.setAdapter(new CustomListViewAdapter1(this, image_details));          
count1.setText(size+"  comments");
count3.setText(size+"  comments");
Intent intent2 = getIntent();
Bundle b = intent2.getExtras();
final  String username= b.getString("UserName");       
System.out.println("username:"+username);          
final  String password= b.getString("Password");                
System.out.println("password:"+password);               
final  String id2= b.getString("id");                
System.out.println("id:"+id2);                           
singleClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                             
                            @Override               
public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub   
            //post();                                                                    
String url = "http://192.168.0.199:8080/CarKonect/webresources/rest/commentInsert";

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);  

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserName", username));                       
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password",password));                                    
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id2));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description",
singleClickComment.getText().toString()));
JSONParser1 jParser = new JSONParser1();         
// getting JSON string from URL along with list values
             JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, method,                   
            nameValuePairs);

         try {  

              String value=(String) json.get("error");
              System.out.println("error:"+value);
              String value1=(String) json.get("Inserted");
              System.out.println("insert value:"+value1);                           
              if(value1.equals("true"))
              {
                Intent homeintent=new Intent(SingleClickComment.this,HomeActivity.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("UserName", username);          
                b.putString("Password",password);
                homeintent.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(homeintent);
              }                     
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
                }           
            }           
                    });         
                }    

      private ArrayList<Comment> GetSearchResults() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              Intent intent2 = getIntent();
              Bundle b = intent2.getExtras();
              final  String username= b.getString("UserName");
              System.out.println("username:"+username);
              final  String password= b.getString("Password");
              System.out.println("password:"+password);
              final  String id2= b.getString("id");
              System.out.println("id:"+id2);

              ArrayList<Comment> results = new ArrayList<Comment>();
              String url = "http://192.168.0.199:8080/CarKonect/webresources/rest/readSingleQuery";

              List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2); 
              nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id2));
              nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserName", username));
              nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password",password));
              JSONParser1 jParser = new JSONParser1();

              // getting JSON string from URL along with list values
              JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, method,nameValuePairs);                                       
              try {                 
              Comment undergraduateDetailsPojoObj = new Comment();
              String description=(String) json.get("Description");
              System.out.println(description);
              enquires=(String) json.get("Query_Id");
              System.out.println( enquires);
              String title=(String) json.get("Title");
              System.out.println(title);
              servicestatusapp=(String) json.get("Query_Status");                           
              System.out.println(servicestatusapp);
              JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("historyList");
              size=jsonArray.length();
              System.out.println(size);     
                for(int i=0;i<=size;i++)
                {   
                JSONObject c1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                username1=(String) c1.get("Response_From_Name");     
                inserteddate1=(String) c1.get("Inserted_Date");                                     
                description4=(String) c1.get("Description");  
                undergraduateDetailsPojoObj.setUserName(username1); 
                undergraduateDetailsPojoObj.setImage(1);
                undergraduateDetailsPojoObj.setInsertedDate(inserteddate1);
                undergraduateDetailsPojoObj.setDescription(description4);
                results.add(undergraduateDetailsPojoObj);
                }

                }catch (JSONException e1) {                     
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                     e1.printStackTrace();
                }   
                return results;     
              } 
              }
```

**singleclick.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
   android:layout_width="match_parent"          
  android:layout_height="match_parent"            
 android:background="#2f322a" >                 
 <LinearLayout             
   android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"              
  android:layout_width="match_parent"             
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >              
  <LinearLayout                
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"                   
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"                   
 android:layout_height="match_parent"                   
 android:layout_weight="0.01"                
   android:orientation="vertical" >            
 </LinearLayout>                  
  <LinearLayout                      
  android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"                       
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"                      
  android:layout_height="match_parent"                      
  android:layout_weight="0.99"                      
  android:orientation="vertical" >         
 <TableRow                          
  android:id="@+id/tableRow1"                      
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"                         
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"                      
     android:orientation="vertical" >          
 <LinearLayout           
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"              
  android:layout_width="match_parent"              
  android:layout_height="match_parent"               
 android:orientation="horizontal" >        
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"           
 android:orientation="vertical"           
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"           
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"          
  android:scrollbars="vertical"           
 >        
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"            
android:orientation="horizontal"            
style="@style/TitleBar"         
android:layout_width = "fill_parent"            
android:layout_height="43dp"        
    android:gravity="left|top">     
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"                    
  android:orientation="horizontal"                  
  android:layout_width = "wrap_content"                 
  android:layout_height="50dp"                  
  android:gravity="left"                    
  android:background="@drawable/customerbg"                 
  >                             
  <Button style="@style/TitleBarOperation"                          
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"                           
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                              
      android:drawableTop="@drawable/user"                          
android:id="@+id/userslide"                                                     
   android:textSize="10dp"                          
       android:layout_marginTop="2dp"                               
   android:layout_marginRight="10dip"                               
   android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"                                                 
   android:background="@drawable/home_bg"                               
   android:layout_gravity="center"                              
   android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"                                 
   />                           
  <ImageView android:layout_width="1px"                 
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"                 
   android:background="@drawable/divider"                   
   android:layout_marginRight="5dip"/>                  
  <Button style="@style/TitleBarOperation"                   
              android:drawableTop="@drawable/write"                         
     android:text="Write"                           
     android:id="@+id/onwrite"                          
       android:textSize="10dp"                                  
   android:layout_marginRight="10dip"                               
   android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"                             
   android:layout_marginBottom = "5dip"                             
   android:paddingBottom = "3dip"                               
   android:background="@drawable/home_bg"                               
   android:layout_gravity="center"                              
    />               
 <Button style="@style/TitleBarOperation"                                       
     android:id="@+id/onschedule"                           
       android:layout_width="50dp"                              
   android:drawableTop="@drawable/schedule"                         
      android:text="Schedule"                              
   android:textSize="10dp"                               
  android:layout_marginRight="5dip"                             
   android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"                               
 android:layout_marginBottom = "5dip"                                
  android:paddingBottom = "3dip"                                
   android:background="@drawable/home_bg"                               
   android:layout_gravity="center"                          
        />                   
  <Button style="@style/TitleBarOperation"                     
    android:layout_width="50dp"                                                     
  android:id="@+id/feedback"                                
   android:drawableTop="@drawable/feedback"                             
   android:text="Feedback"                               
  android:textSize="10dp"                              
   android:layout_marginTop="3dp"                               
   android:layout_marginRight="10dip"                                
  android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"                                
 android:layout_marginBottom = "5dip"                                
  android:paddingBottom = "3dip"                                 
  android:background="@drawable/home_bg"                                
   android:layout_gravity="center"                          
        />                    
 <Button style="@style/TitleBarOperation"                        
  android:layout_width="50dp"                               
 android:layout_marginTop="1dp"                             
   android:id="@+id/truevalue"                              
  android:drawableTop="@drawable/truevalue"                             
  android:text="Truevalue"                              
  android:textSize="10dp"                               
   android:layout_marginRight="15dip"                               
   android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"                              
  android:layout_marginBottom = "5dip"                              
   android:paddingBottom = "3dip"                                      android:background="@drawable/home_bg"                               
   android:layout_gravity="center"                              
    />                     
 <ImageView android:layout_width="1px"                    
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"                      
 android:background="@drawable/divider"                
   android:layout_marginRight="1dip"/>                          
 <Button style="@style/TitleBarOperation"                                
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/dealer"                          
      android:id="@+id/dealer"                             
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"                                                    
   android:layout_marginRight="10dip"                               
   android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"                             
   android:layout_marginBottom = "5dip"                             
   android:paddingBottom = "3dip"                                
  android:background="@drawable/home_bg"                                  
 android:layout_gravity="center"                                
    />      
    </LinearLayout>         
</LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"                          
        android:orientation="horizontal"                                       android:layout_width = "fill_parent"                             
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                  
  android:background="#C0C0C0">        
     <TextView                  
 android:id="@+id/serviceEnduiry_Id"             
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"            
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"             
 android:layout_marginRight="30sp"          
  />        
     <TextView                  
 android:id="@+id/serviceappointmentstatus"          
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"              
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"                 
 />        
 </LinearLayout>               
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"          
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"               
android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
  android:orientation="vertical"           
 android:background="#2f322a"              
android:paddingLeft="10sp"          
   >           
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"            
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"              
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
 android:orientation="horizontal"           
   android:layout_marginTop="2sp"            
 android:paddingLeft="10sp"            
  >          
     <ImageView             
    android:id="@+id/ImageCity1"               
  android:paddingTop="3sp"               
  android:layout_width="20sp"             
    android:src="@drawable/coment"              
  android:layout_height="20sp"              
   android:contentDescription="desc"                
  android:paddingLeft="5sp"/>              
         <TextView                
   android:id="@+id/Count1"                 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"                
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"                 
  android:textSize="12sp"                 
  android:layout_marginRight="50sp"                 
  android:textColor="#A1A1A1"                   
 android:paddingLeft="5sp" />                  
      <TextView               
    android:id="@+id/Time1"                
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"                 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"              
     android:textSize="12sp"                 
  android:textColor="#A1A1A1"  />                   
       </LinearLayout>                    
   <TextView                
   android:id="@+id/Comment1"               
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"                  
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"                 
  android:textSize="15sp"                  
 android:textStyle="bold"              
     android:layout_marginRight="30sp"                 
 android:textColor="#ffffff"                  
  android:paddingLeft="10sp"                 
  android:layout_marginBottom="4sp" />                 
  <TextView                 
 android:id="@+id/DEscription1"                  
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"             
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"                 
  android:textSize="13sp"                  
 android:paddingLeft="10sp"                  
 android:textColor="#A1A1A1"  />             
      </LinearLayout>                    
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"                               
    android:orientation="vertical"                             
    android:layout_width = "fill_parent"                                
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"                             
        android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"                 
android:layout_marginRight="10sp"                          >        
<TextView             
android:layout_width="fill_parent"             
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"             
  android:text="WikiCode - Custom ExpandableListView"       
      />            
<ExpandableListView                 
android:id="@+id/ExpandableListView01"                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
android:layout_width="fill_parent"              
android:background="#C0C0C0"                
android:childDivider="#848482"          
>           
</ExpandableListView>           
 <TextView                 
  android:id="@+id/Count2"                 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"                  
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"                 
  android:textSize="12sp"                 
  android:layout_marginRight="50sp"                  
 android:textColor="#A1A1A1"               
     android:paddingLeft="5sp" />
       <ListView android:id="@+id/list10"               
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"               
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
 android:background="#C0C0C0"                
  android:textColor="#A1A1A1"                
 ></ListView>    
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"             
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"              
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"          
  android:orientation="horizontal"           
   android:layout_marginTop="2sp"          
   android:paddingLeft="10sp"           
   >               
 <EditText android:id="@+id/singleclickcommententry"              
    android:layout_width="150sp"             
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
            />        
      <Button android:id="@+id/singleclickcommentbutton"             
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"              
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
         android:text="send"              
    />        
            </LinearLayout>                 
</LinearLayout>              
</LinearLayout>         
    </LinearLayout>            
     </TableRow>            
</LinearLayout>        
</LinearLayout>    
    </FrameLayout>
```

**LOGCAT REPORT**

> 01-02 12:18:19.072: E/AndroidRuntime(3286): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 01-02 12:18:19.072: E/AndroidRuntime(3286): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidactionbar/com.example.androidactionbar.SingleClickComment}: java.lang.NullPointerException 01-02 12:18:19.072: E/AndroidRuntime(3286): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663) 01-02 12:18:19.072: E/AndroidRuntime(3286): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679) 01-02 12:18:19.072: E/AndroidRuntime(3286): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125) 01-02 12:18:19.072: E/AndroidRuntime(3286): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033) 01-02 12:18:19.072: E/AndroidRuntime(3286): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 01-02 12:18:19.072: E/AndroidRuntime(3286): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 01-02 12:18:19.072: E/AndroidRuntime(3286): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 01-02 12:18:19.072: E/AndroidRuntime(3286): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 01-02 12:18:19.072: E/AndroidRuntime(3286): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 01-02 12:18:19.072: E/AndroidRuntime(3286): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858) 01-02 12:18:19.072: E/AndroidRuntime(3286): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 01-02 12:18:19.072: E/AndroidRuntime(3286): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 01-02 12:18:19.072: E/AndroidRuntime(3286): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 01-02 12:18:19.072: E/AndroidRuntime(3286): at com.example.androidactionbar.SingleClickComment.onCreate(SingleClickComment.java:82) 01-02 12:18:19.072: E/AndroidRuntime(3286): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047) 01-02 12:18:19.072: E/AndroidRuntime(3286): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627) 01-02 12:18:19.072: E/AndroidRuntime(3286): ... 11 more

Comment: format properly this question.. its too big and not able to figure out ..

Comment: where is your logcat error report?

Comment: @Andro Selva please give me the suggestion

Comment: Could you at least highlight line 82 in the code of your SingleClickComment class? That's where your error is, but it's too much code and blank lines to simply look through it all...

Comment: @TofferJ LINE 82:lv1.setAdapter(new CustomListViewAdapter1(this, image_details));

Comment: but it works fine in android 2.2 device

Comment: Please add your logcat error report without which no one can help you

Comment: @almuneef added my logcat report

Comment: add your layout files here...

Comment: @DhavalSodhaParmar please check the attached files

Comment: In the activity you have set singleclick as layout file
You have attached a layout for MYSINGLECLICK

Comment: @almuneef:sorry that layout file is singleclick.xml file only i mentiod by mistake it as my application singleclick.xml

Comment: There is no listview with id list10 in your layout
replace it with the correct Id

Comment: sorry the layout code also having

Comment: <ListView android:id="@+id/list10"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="#C0C0C0"
          android:textColor="#A1A1A1" 
        ></ListView>

Comment: i dont no how to post the code thats y the code was hidden

Comment: @prasanth : please read this link and formate your question first. after that any one can answer your question. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: @DhavalSodhaParmar hi i formatted my questions by using that site.please study the code once

Comment: How i differentiate your layout files please formate your code again. give file name with code.

Comment: @DhavalSodhaParmar hi sir please refer the code i changed the layout file name

Comment: here is your ans : change this  if(image_details.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase("service_appointment")) and put try{}catch(){} in your singleClick.setOnClickListener debug it because you have local web services so i can't check here.

Comment: @DhavalSodhaParmar  lv1.setAdapter(new CustomListViewAdapter1(this, image_details));  geeting the logcat error in debugging

Answer (score 1):

change

```
final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list10);
```

to

```
final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ExpandableListView01);
```

I believe that ExpandableListView01 is the id of your list view